# Pulling value from HTML table to put into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I am working on a website that pulls information from a database table and places it into an HTML table.  I am using the Jquery click function and contenteditable to make table cells editable when clicked. I am trying to figure out the best way push the value that was edited back into the database.  Each row of the database has a unique date so my thoughts were to use that as the search parameter to find the correct database entry, paired with the column number.  I was trying to use `$(this).bind('input propertychange', function() {` and then ajax after contenteditable but was told that placing functions inside of functions was a bad idea so I was hoping that someone else could help me come up with a better idea.  Here is a quick working example of the table to save some time for anyone playing around with code to try to help me.  Thanks for the help in advance guys!!

```js
            $('td').click(function(){
                var val=($(this).siblings().first().text());
                var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
                $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
                //var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
                //alert('Date: ' + val + ', Column: ' + col);
            });
```

```css
            table,th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                font-size: 90%;
            }
            th, td {
                padding:8px;
            }
            td {
                text-align: center;
            }
            table {
                margin:0 auto;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><th></th><th>22oz Dark</th><th>12ct 4oz Dark</th></tr><tr><th>2016-01-01</th><td>9785</td><td>2478</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-02</th><td>8754</td><td>2136</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-03</th><td>13587</td><td>2203</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-04</th><td>14111</td><td>3297</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-05</th><td>13212</td><td>3101</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-06</th><td>16335</td><td>3299</td></tr><tr><th>2016-01-07</th><td>15421</td><td>3100</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing a function inside a function is commonly done in JavaScript. Callback functions and closures are exactly that.

I would recommend you add some type of event listener to the input and when they are done editing you can just get the value of that input and make an AJAX call.

So maybe don't always make the input editable, and on click you add that attribute. And you use jQuery to target it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to go ahead and post the solution for the issue I was having for future readers.  instead of trying to use bind I went with keyup ( I was not aware at first that keyup ment key release).  So using the following code I am now able to do exactly what I was trying to do when I posted this question:

```
$(this).keyup(function() {

                    //keyup means when a key is released

                    $.ajax({
                      method: "POST",
                      url: "updatedatabase.php",
                      data: { content: $(this).text() }
                    })
                      .done(function( msg ) {
                        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                    });

                 });
            });
```